# The convergence of a strange integral: $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x-1}{\ln x}\mathbb dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

- For this integral， I do not know how to tell prove
  that$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x-1}{\ln x}\mathbb dx$$is convergent using
  the definition of "improper integral".
- I can show that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-1}{lnx}=0$ and $\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x-1}{lnx}=1$ to show the integral is indeed not "improper", but my instructor believes it's not sufficient, since he might want me to do the proof by $\varepsilon$.
- Another note on how I get the value of $ln2$: consider $$f(x)=\int_{x}^{x^2}\frac{1}{lnt} \mathbb dt, x\in(0,1)$$Then $f'(x)=\frac{x-1}{\ln x}$. By Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, and $$\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0, \lim_{x\to1}f(x)=ln2$$
  I find that $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x-1}{\ln x}\mathbb dx=f(1)-f(0)=ln2$$. Although I've computed the value, it still requires something first to say the integral is convergent. That's where I was wondering.

Comment: For one, it's doubly improper

Comment: Would not the fact that it evaluates to a finite value - that being $\ln 2$ - be sufficient to say it converges? Are you supposed to use certain techniques to determine the convergence beyond mere calculation, or am I just missing something altogether?

Comment: By changing variables with $u = \log(x)$ we get the integral $$-\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-2x}-e^{-x}}{x}dx$$ which is simply $\log(2)$ by Frullani's Theorem. Since we get a finite value, the interval converges.

Comment: I am thinking of a more basic method...

Comment: What do you mean by "more basic"? Brevan's answer lends itself to a one- or two-line proof if one is familiar with the context. You should clarify what really is fair game for us so that we might help you, because we simply don't know what you *do* know.

Comment: Well, I think Frullani's Theorem is a bit advanced for me..

Comment: How do you know the integral converges to that value?

Comment: Do you know either Fubini's Theorem or Tonelli's Theorem? If so, consider the two integrals $\int_0^1\int_0^1x^y\,dx\,dy$ and $\int_0^1\int_0^1x^y\,dy\,dx$. Can you show that they exist, are finite, and are equal? After that, try evaluating them.

Answer (score 3):

It converges at zero because
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-1}{\ln x}=0 
$$
so it is not actually improper there. From the left of $x=1$ you have $\ln x\sim x-1$ as $x\to 1^-$ and the limit is $1$. Therefore this integral is not improper at all!

Answer (score 3):

This function is continuous over $(0,1)$ and $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}{x-1\over \ln x}=0\\\lim_{x\to 1^-}{x-1\over \ln x}=1$$therefore the integral converges. Here is a sketch of the function:
[image]